# High quality Space-related blog/website?

Tags: space

I don't know if this is the right place for asking this question, my apologies in advance. I would like to be updated on the latests news on space and I am looking for a website devoted to space news, or a blog. I was only able to find minor blogs which were not updated often. Could you suggest me a high quality blog/space related website that you know? Thanks!

Comment: Hm. I am not sure if this kind of questions are on topic or not. Do we have a policy on it?

Comment: @Hohmannfan there was a request about this (though for more professional-oriented sites) a while ago: [here](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14359/a-good-website-for-laymen-to-share-their-discoveries).  I wonder if there is a general list of resources anywhere. (I think I have seen a list of books, though my memory may be wrong.)

Comment: I agree with @Hohmannfan, especially since questions like these can be solved with a quick Google search.

Comment: @SirCumference as I wrote in the text of my question, I wasn't sure that this kind of question was allowed on this site. However, a simple answer provided by experts on the field or people that share my same interests are way higher than any query that I could ever type on Google

Comment: @cholo14 This isn't a question that needs an expert response, though. I'm sure this would be better asked on another site.

Comment: @SirCumference Since the OP especially asks for *high quality* and only found *minor blogs* it may need more human intelligence/experience than a simple Google search. But indeed, list questions are questionably on/off-topic. Here: http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/266/list-of-resources  Building a large canonical answer could be helpful. I have edited my answer into a community wiki.

Comment: @SirCumference That is true, but experts might be better placed to answer it than most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question for "space" news sites is somewhat vague as space can cover a wide variety of topics.

I have found [Innerspace.net](http://innerspace.net/)  to be a nice blog/news source primarily concerning itself with the space exploration and technology aspects of space. It often reports on recent launches (such as those by Space X), advancements in space technologies, and space ventures by other countries outside the US such as China and Russia.

If you're looking for more sciencey topics of a higher caliber, try something like [Science Daily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/news/space_time/). While this covers a variety of scientific fields, it does also cover space news. In general, this site is a curation of articles by various sources. Usually each article is linked to some specific scientific research or published paper.

Comment: You are right, my question for "space" was somewhat vague, but actually I'm interested in both Astrophysics/new discoveries in space and Space exploration. So I found the sites very interesting, thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Emily Lakdawalla's blog at the Planetary Society](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/) is good for hard science news about our solar system, especially planetary exploration, of course. There are occasional guest authors as well.